# Add field dynamically in symfony2

Tags: symfony

Hi guys I want to know how to change a form in `symfony` dynamically  without using an entity. 
Here's what I mean

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
            ->add('Energie', ChoiceType::class , array(
                                    'choices'  => array(
                                        'ELEC' => 'ELEC',
                                        'GAZ' => 'GAZ',
                                        'DUAL' => 'DUAL',
                                    );
}
```

For example if I choose `ELEC` I add another input field. 
I don't use any entity with this form.

EDIT:
Maybe I can use code like this :

```
->add('PCE',  TextType::class, array(   'label' => "PCE",
                                        'required' => false))
->add('CARGAZ',  TextType::class, array('label' => "CAR 
                                        'required' => false))
```

I use a JS code to show on of this two field and make it required, after in the controller I persist the field I need and in case of error ( or if the JS code didn't work I back with an error using ->addError(new FormError('PCE empty'));
What do you think ?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: Which version of symfony are you using?

Comment: I use symfony 2.8.2.